# Cannot findOne by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Find on Index, return results.

Method:

```
async index(req,res){
        const user = await Usuario.find();
        res.json(user);
    },
```

Route:

```
routes.get('/api/usuarios', Usuario.index);
```

**but findOne({_id}) cannot get results Help pls(i have tryied change params by query, but doesn't works)**

method:

```
async details(req,res){
        const { _id } = req.params;
        const user = await Usuario.findOne({_id});
        res.json(user);
},
```

route:

```
routes.get('/api/usuarios.details/', Usuario.details);
```

Comment: Can you console log the req.params, then you should be able to tell the query key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change your route

```
routes.get('/api/usuarios/:_id', Usuario.details);
```

Then you need to call API like below

```
http://localhost:<your port number>/api/usuarios/<your id>
```

Then In your controller

```
Usuario.findOne(
   { _id: req.params._id }
)
```

Comment: it works, just with adjust on route :) tks god!

Answer (score 0):

```
async details(req,res){
    const { _id } = req.params;
    const user = await Usuario.findOne({_id: _id});
    res.json(user);
},
```

Try the above

Comment: get ObjectId() from 'mongodb' module and pass the id as param to the ObjectId(id) like this

Comment: if I set the id on code, it returns result

async details(req,res){
        const { _id } = req.params;
        const user = await Usuario.findOne({_id: '603ff264ddeecb2750287a4d'});
        res.json(user);
    },
but i need to find it :'(